# Properly removing /public and connecting files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vps, host

I've seen a lot of similiar topics and I tried all of them and previously it worked, every time different one, but now nothing...

So I  want to remove  /public from my URL and it works for laravel-public_html but not for build version

I'm using VPS (CentOS 7 with CWP 7)

My structure is like this:

```
/home/admin/
-laravel
-public_html (public folder for laravel)
-laravel_build
-build (public folder for laravel_build)
```

and with that I have build.mypage.com and www.mypage.com

httpd.conf

```
...
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache"
...
DocumentRoot "/home/admin/public_html"
<Directory "/home/admin/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

index.php (public_html)

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

index.php (build)

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel_build/bootstrap/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel_build/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Should I add something in .htaccess , and if yes, where do I need to put that .htaccess?

Edit: I already have .htaccess in public folders for laravel routes(mod _rewrite)

Comment: You don't seem to be using the framework required folder structure.

Comment: Do you have another entry in httpd.conf for build path ? Essentially you have two apps as per my understanding ... one from public_html and another from build. so don't you need two entries in apache conf file for two domain names if I understand correctly?

Comment: @apokryfos as I said it worked before so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: @Andy yes, it indeed is two apps, I guess I do need two entries, but how to make it?

Comment: @Cgdl you're wasting your time fixing something that you don't need to fix if you just follow the framework guidelines. You probably have better things to do with your time. Just setup 2 vhosts

Comment: @apokryfos can you tell me how to make vhosts and what is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: Check out https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html in short you can tell apache that if you visit `domain1.example.com` it should serve files from 1 folder and if you visit `domain2.example.com` it should serve files from another folder by setting different document roots for different domains. For testing locally you can also add those domains to your `hosts` file so they point to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using something like MAMP or XAMP, if possible do not add anything in httpd.comf, instead you could do something
like below in your httpd-vhosts.conf.

You may have to look for a directory in your environment where to put the virtual host file (and sometime you have to uncomment that path in your httpd.conf)

Example of entry in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yourEmail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/admin/laravel/public_html"
    ServerName MySite1.com
    ServerAlias MySite1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/MySite1_com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/MySite1_com_access.log" common
    php_value error_log "logs/php_error.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yourEmail@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/admin/build"
    ServerName subdomain.MySite1.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.MySite1.com
    ErrorLog "logs/subdoamain-MySite1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/subdoamain-MySite1-error.log" common
    php_value error_log "logs/php_error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Add two entries for both the apps.

Comment: Okay, I found vhosts.conf and it appears that there's already  two different vHosts there (probably generated by CWP) when I created subdomain

Comment: In your httpd.conf there should be an include for the vhost file (which should have its path). You need to uncomment that and add your website config in that file as I indicated above. If vhost file is already enabled then thats fine you can still add your own virtualHost entries and serve your site from any folder in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid now, **the problem** was actually that I did not **Hard Reset and Clear Cache** in Google Chrome so it loaded previous configuration

For others that have similiar problem, solutions to try:

1.**Create vHosts for subdomain and domain**

2.**Put .htaccess in public folder, not laravel folder**

My current .htaccess is as follows(both public_html and build):

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```